# Is there a AMQP implementation that has stable C++ Client library

Tags: c++, amqp

Is there a AMQP implementation that has stable C++ Client library

Answer (score 5):

Apache Qpid has a stable C++ client library -- see [qpid.apache.org](http://qpid.apache.org/).

Answer (score 2):

### RabbitMQ:

https://github.com/alanxz/SimpleAmqpClient

https://github.com/akalend/amqpcpp

### Apache Qpid:

https://qpid.apache.org/apis/0.16/cpp/html/

### Reviews on Message Brokers

(RabbitMQ and Apache Qpid came out on top for their uses)
http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/Message_Queue_Evaluation_Notes#RabbitMQ

Answer (score 1):

See [Apache Active MQ Cpp](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/) for one example

Comment: ? Is this *AMQP*, rather than ActiveMQ ? The two are different.

Comment: AMQP is a standard, Active MQ is an implementation of it (at least that's my understanding of http://activemq.apache.org/amqp.html)

Comment: ActiveMQ does not implement AMQP yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is a C client for RabbitMQ and a C++ interface for it is being discussed on the mailing list right now.

http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2010-March/006547.html

Cheers

alexis