# AMQP C Library for Small Embedded Devices

Tags: c, amqp

I am looking for a AMQP library, preferably written in C, that will work on a small embedded device. i.e. no OS and limited RAM and code size space (256k between both RAM and code).

I have seen the following post and number of others, I have looked into Qpid and RabbitMQ, but none seem suited to a small device.

[Is there a AMQP implementation that has stable C++ Client library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261421/is-there-a-amqp-implementation-that-has-stable-c-client-library/2374297#2374297)

Can anyone suggest a AMQP library that will work on a microcontroller? All functionality is not essential, even just support for telemetry would be good.

Comment: While this question is off-topic, have you seen https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c? I guess it is first result in google. It is named in way that one might think that is targeted to work only with RabbitMQ, but is not. It can work with any AMQP-compatible AMQP broker. As of written, it supports only 0-9-1 AMQP protocol. In issues (or PRs) there was talks that someone use it in some ebedded device.

Comment: AMQP is often considered too big and complex to be put on small embedded devices - and instead a simpler protocol is used, such as having MQTT (I've seen a few use STOMP, or simply a proprietrary protocol) running on the device, and transforming the messages to AMQP or another protocol by either a dedicated gateway to perform the conversion or a general message broker that supports both AMQP and MQTT

Comment: I am aware of the MQTT and gateway or broker method. My goal is to communicate directly with Azure Service Bus/Event Hubs, which do not support MQTT at this stage. For superior scalability, direct communication would be best.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be an old question, but maybe this still helps.

Disclaimer: I am one of the authors of uamqp-c.

There are 2 choices I know of:

-Qpic Proton C: https://github.com/apache/qpid-proton

-uamqp-c: https://github.com/Azure/azure-uamqp-c

Cheers,
/Dan

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looking for an alternative to QPid Proton.